# Confusion with ListView adapters

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor

I'm having some trouble understanding how to get my ListView to update. When a user clicks on a list item, the item is deleted fromt he database and the ListView should update to show it no longer there. However, the list does not update and I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.mediacatalogue;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

    public class DVDs extends ListActivity {
    private DatabaseHelper database;
    private static final String MEDIA_TYPE = "DVD";
    private Cursor ListCursor;
    private BaseAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        database.open();

        ListCursor = database.selectMedia(MEDIA_TYPE);
        database.close();
        startManagingCursor(ListCursor);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listlayout,
            ListCursor,
            new String[] {DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME+".title", DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME+".author"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
                database.open();
                database.deleteMedia(String.valueOf(id));
                ListCursor = database.selectMedia(MEDIA_TYPE);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                database.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know the database updates correctly as when you exit and reenter the application the list displays as it should, it just doesn't update when an Item is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your Adapter.

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`? That's already there after updating the cursor.

Comment: why You use setListAdapter(adapter); in onitemclicklistner ?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how to get the list to update and thought that maybe that would cause the list to reload or something.

Answer (score 0):

Does this variant work?

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            database.open();
            database.deleteMedia(String.valueOf(id));
            database.close();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // maybe use notifyDataSetInvalidated()
        }
    });
```